# How to share data between roles?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, permissions, acl

I'am creating an Angular(8) app. I have roles and permissions set up. Some users can enter specifics pages or do specific actions (based on role and permissions that roles have), some cannot. I want to do next:

Lets say that I have admin user that can create some preset(settings) of certain table, I want him to be able to share that stored settings to other roles and/or specific user(s). What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Having a database.

Comment: You have to read about Angular's AuthGuards. Usefull articles [this](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) and [this](https://codeburst.io/using-angular-route-guard-for-securing-routes-eabf5b86b4d1)

Comment: The users will use different browsers (clients), so it is not possible to share the data locally. That means you have to store the data in the backend and provide it to the other users.